# How to remove lines from TSV file where columns are empty or all whitespace?

Tags: grep, csv, text, delete

I've a tab-delimited file, e.g. `myfile.tsv`:

```
abc\tfoo
xyz\tbar
```

but sometimes, it has some blank columns, e.g.

```
abc\tfoo
xyz\tbar
what\t
\tthe
bleep\tsleep
```

i.e.

```
$ printf "abc\tfoo\n" > myfile.tsv
printf "xyz\tbar\n" >> myfile.tsv
printf "what\t\n" >> myfile.tsv
printf "\tthe\n" >> myfile.tsv
printf "bleep\tsleep\n" >> myfile.tsv

$ cat myfile.tsv 
abc foo
xyz bar
what    
    the
bleep   sleep
```

I could write a python script to remove the lines where the columns are empty, e.g.

```
with open('myfile.tsv') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        x, y = line.strip().split('\t')
        x = x.strip()
        y = y.strip()
        if x and y:
            print(line)
```

But **how do I do the same with some unix shell commands, e.g. `grep`, `sed`, `awk` or something.**

---

I've tried also something like this in `grep`:

```
grep -e ".\t." myfile.tsv
```

That seems to work but if the columns have spaces, it won't.

```
$ printf "abc\tfoo\n" > myfile.tsv
printf "xyz\tbar\n" >> myfile.tsv
printf "what\t  \n" >> myfile.tsv
printf "  \tthe\n" >> myfile.tsv
printf "bleep\tsleep\n" >> myfile.tsv

$ grep -e ".\t." myfile.tsv       
abc foo
xyz bar
what      
    the
bleep   sleep
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Miller (`mlr`):

```bash
$ cat -t myfile.tsv
abc^Ifoo
xyz^Ibar
^I
what^I
^Ithe
bleep^Isleep
```

```bash
$ mlr --tsv filter 'bool empty=false ; for (k,v in $*) { empty = is_empty(v); empty { break }  } !empty' myfile.tsv
abc     foo
xyz     bar
bleep   sleep
```

The equivalent thing in `awk`:

```bash
$ awk -F '\t' '{ empty = 1; for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) if (empty = (length($i) == 0)) break }; !empty' myfile.tsv
abc     foo
xyz     bar
bleep   sleep
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E '/^\t|\t$/d' myfile.tsv
abc     foo
xyz     bar
bleep   sleep
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove lines where the ALL fields on that line either contain only spaces, tabs, or are empty, you can match and exclude lines containing *only whitespace*:

```
grep -v '^[[:space:]]*$'
```